# Eclipse + JBoss - some JAR files not deployed

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss

I have an Eclipse Indigo installation with a JBoss 6 server managed by it. I have a Maven project with a few modules. These modules all build just fine from the command line.

One of the modules is an EAR. This is dependent on two JAR modules and a couple of WAR modules. When I package the EAR from the command line (mvn clean package), the EAR contains all the necessary JAR and WAR files. However, when I deploy it from Eclipse, the two module JAR files are missing from JBoss. The WAR files are just fine. Inside the "Add and Remove..." dialog the JAR files are also present, but not when deployed. I've checked JBoss' deployments folder and there they are indeed missing. The strange thing is, with the exact same POMs and code, all of my colleagues with the same(?) setup don't have this problem.

The two JAR modules are listed in the dependency management part of the parent POM. They are also listed as dependencies in the EAR POM. Still, Eclipse refuses to deploy them with the EAR.

Does anybody have any idea how I can solve this issue? I can manually package and deploy the EAR, but 1) that takes longer, and 2) I can't use Eclipse's debugging functionality this way.

Note: previously asked at http://www.coderanch.com/t/580959/vc/Eclipse-JBoss-some-JAR-files

Comment: Why can't you debug with Eclipse? I manually package my ear with mvn, and I always debug it with the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Right mouse button on project -> Maven -> Update project

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the exact same issue, different eclipse (Eclipse Mars, WildFly 8.1 ).

The unsettling part was that I didn't change anything in the code or in the IDE (that I am aware of) and it started malfunctioning.

I suspect it has something to do with the cached memory of eclipse for it's plugins, anyway, after many hours of trying different things **we fixed it by deleting the folder .eclipse under your user in windows.**

Seems silly, but we tried everything except that, and that thing did the trick

Answer (score 1):

I'm encountering a similar issue, however my environment is much, much simpler - being a web project, with a utility project. Not using maven at all and deploying to tomcat7.

The class file is not being deployed to the web-inf as expected, although the utility project is referenced, and marked as to be exported.

However with your issue, I came across this post:

http://blog.frankel.ch/better-maven-integration-leads-to-unforeseen-consequences-bugs#comments

which might provide a clue. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, after getting a few more Eclipse problems, I threw away my existing Eclipse installation and workspace and started afresh. Although I have done that before to no avail, this time it worked.

Comment: And speak of the devil, the problem has returned in full effect. A complete removal of Eclipse or the workspace doesn't help anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I didn't modify my code at all, I deleted all the projects from the work space, closed eclipse and reopened it.  Then I did a clean and build of the project (which took much longer than before).  This time when I went to add the EAR project, it had all the dependencies listed and actually worked.